# c# property setter not called when invoked from visual designer

Tags: c#, properties, setter

I came across some strange behaviour in visual studio 2012

to simulate, create a custom control inherited from DataSet
Add a property like this :

```
    private string _test = "";
    public string Test
    {
        get { return _test; }
        set
        {
            _test = value;
            MessageBox.Show(_test);
        }
    }
```

now place the component on a winform, and set a value to the property Test to for example "123"
you will see the mesagebox appear saying "123"
now set the same value again to this property, you will not see the messagebox appear
Only after setting a different value in the property the setter will be called again.

If you make a class in for example a console application (and use writeline instead of messagebox offcourse) you will see that assigning the same value does calls the setter each time again, but when using the custom control in winform assiging the same value to the property does not call setter each time again.

Why is this and how can I get around this ?

Comment: It's not unreasonable for the `PropertyGrid` to only call the setter when the value has changed.  Why do you need the other behavior?

Comment: +1, I'm pretty sure the issue is not related to winforms, I think it's just that properties doesn't do anything if the value is the same, and I'd like to know why :D

Comment: @Kilazur No, it's the WinForm PropertyGrid designer doing that.  At runtime, the MessageBox will always appear.

Comment: @Lars Actually makes sense, yeah... (°3°)

Comment: @adv12 The property I need is holding the name of a file. This file can be changed at any time by anybode. So if I want my setter code to get executed again after my file has changed, I need to assign a dummy file to my property and then assign my filename back again. I agree that most of the time there is no use in calling the setters code when assigning the same value, but I do not agree that I do not have a choice in this.

Comment: @adv12 I have no problem that the setter is called when the value is changed, I have a problem that the setter is NOT called.

Comment: @user3611669, I think you're misunderstanding where the "not calling" is happening.  The `PropertyGrid` control, used by the Windows Forms Designer, apparently has the (perfectly reasonable) optimization that it will only call a property's setter when you change the text in the `PropertyGrid`.  As such, unless you are using a `PropertyGrid` in your code, you needn't worry about this optimization at runtime.

Comment: @adv12 I think you're misunderstanding my problem. I have a case here where the "optimization" is not reasonable. I agree that almost always there will be no reason to call the setter again when assigning the same value, but there are a few exceptions when you do want it to be called everytime. This is on of them. So my question is not anymore why this is (seems to be some "optimization" by the designer)

Comment: @adv12 (part2 of my comment) but the question is now, how to get arround this and why do I have no choice in this ? Also, because when setting the property in code the "optimization" does not occur, so I have to write in every setter some code to check that the setters code is only executed when the value is different. So why do extra work on an "optimizer" that only "optimizes" in certain conditions but not always. That makes no sense.

Comment: @user3611669, I think I've been as much help as I can be here.  Good luck.

Comment: @adv12 Yes you have been very helpfull. At least I know now who is responsible for not calling my setter and now I have a change to look for a workaround for my problem. Thank you very much